# install python package from github using requirements.txt

Tags: python-3.x, github, pip, setuptools

Whats the successful way to import packages from github repo?

Here is what I tried
Tried Installing a python package- corepkg,  which is available in git repository - git.example.com/corepkg.git

In another Project- Proj2, to import logic from above corepkg package, Kept an entry in requirements.txt and ran the following pip command.

pip install -r requirements.txt

Here are my Entries in requirement.txt for Proj2

```
...
PyYAML==3.12
requests==2.18.4
urllib3==1.22
git+https://git.example.com/corepkg.git@develop
```

But it did not create any src folder or .dist-info folder in virtual environment site-packages? 
It just created corepkg-1-py3.6.egg_info file but not files required to import.

Whats the step I am missing here to import it successfully from git?

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
git+https://git.example.com/corepkg.git@develop#egg=corepkg
```

See https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#vcs-support

The problem also could be in the very `corepkg.git` repo so it's hard to say something without looking at the repo.